# Replace method is not working even after reassigning the value to the string in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, replace

I am trying to replace the values in saopaulo_venues['Venue Category'] for better clustering result but it is not replacing the values in that column.

The code below is the example but there are longer lists of them since there are so many different venues.

I would like to know why this isn't replacing the values.

Thank you in advance.

```
for venue in saopaulo_venues.loc[:, 'Venue Category']:
    if venue == 'Gym / Fitness Center':
        venue = venue.replace('Gym / Fitness Center', 'Gym')
        continue
    elif venue == 'Gymnastics Gym':
        venue = venue.replace('Gymnastics Gym', 'Gym')
        continue
    elif venue == 'College Gym':
        venue = venue.replace('College Gym', 'Gym')
        continue
```

Comment: the str.replace function just assigns the new value to the variable `venue` in that local scope. It doesn't update the list or whatever that is, but you could add another statement to replace the updated value in the list.

Answer (score 0):

How about `replace`:

```
lst = ['Gym / Fitness Center', 'Gymnastics Gym', 'College Gym']
saopaulo_venues['Venue Category'] = saopaulo_venues['Venue Category'].replace(lst, 'Gym')
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked in much shorter lines of code.